# NuxtJS, ExpressJS - how to connect to endpoint correctly?

Tags: express, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to connect to endpoint, I have "POST http://localhost:3000/api/post 404 (Not Found)"

connecting middleware postRoutes to the ./api/index.js:

```
app.use('/post', postRoutes)

export default {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
}
```

postRouter file ./api/routes/post.routes.js:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const ctr = require('../controllers/post.controller')
const router = Router()

router.post('/api/post', ctr.create)

module.exports = router
```

vue page:

```
const formData = {
 title: this.form.title,
 text: this.form.text
}
try {
 await this.$store.dispatch('post/create', formData)
} catch (e) {}
```

so I make a post request to the store ./store/post.js:

```
export const actions = {
  async create({ commit }, formData) {
    try {
      return await this.$axios.$post('/api/post', formData)
    } catch (e) {
      commit('setError', e, { root: true })
      throw e
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `/store/post.js` file when calling axios, did you try to put the full local URL (`http://locallhost:3000/api/post` instead of the relative `/api/post` you have here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way by editing `router.post` before that middleware was observed on `/api/post/api/post`:

```
router.post('/', ctr.create)
```

also my request looks like that:

```
return await this.$axios.$post('/api/post', formData)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you write your full path in axios it will work. Also you can create field in state for base url and use it in actions.

```
return await this.$axios.$post('http://localhost:3000/api/post', formData)
```